# Suddently I get this error "cannot set a Timestamp with a non-timestamp"

Tags: python, linux, pandas, datetime, 32bit-64bit

Still feeling as a newbie. :-)

For some time I have collected stock data from Yahoo both on a Linux Mint 18.2 32-bit and a new Linux Mint 18.2 64-bit.

Suddenly today I get an error on my 64-bit system when plotting the data.
The 32-bit system is working

I get two errors: The first is:

```
The file pandas/_libs/index.pyx could not be opened.
Reason: [Errno 2] Ingen sådan fil eller filkatalog: 'pandas/_libs/index.pyx'
```

It is correct that the file is not in _libs but it do not help to get it from Github and on the 32-bit system it is also missing.

The 32-bit system has pandas 0.20.3 and the 64-bit system has pandas 0.21.0.

I think is was updated when I installed the fix_yahoo_finance on the 64-bit system. My 32-bit system has an old version.
The second error is:

```
Exception "unhandled ValueError"
cannot set a Timestamp with a non-timestamp
File: pandas/_libs/index.pyx, Line: 509
```

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
import datetime


startplot = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

print(startplot)


ferms = glob.glob("DOWJones_stock/*.csv")

for ferm in ferms:
    data = pd.read_csv(ferm,  header=0)
    data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
    data["20d"] = np.round(data["Close"].rolling(window = 20, center = False).mean(), 2)
    data["70d"] = np.round(data["Close"].rolling(window = 70, center = False).mean(), 2)
    data['plot'] = (data['Date'] > startplot) & (data['Date'] <= end) 
    plotdata=data[data['plot']]
    plotdata
    # print(data)
    # data.head()
    pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (25, 14)
    plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 80
    plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 'medium'
    plt.rcParams['figure.titlesize'] = 'large'
    plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = 'true'
    plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.visible'] = 'true'
    plt.rcParams['grid.linestyle'] = '-'
    plt.rcParams['grid.color'] = 'k'
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Close')
    plt.title(ferm)
    plt.plot(plotdata.loc[:,'Date'], plotdata.loc[:,'Close'], 'k', label='Close')
    plt.plot(plotdata.loc[:,'Date'], plotdata.loc[:,'20d'], 'g', label='20d')
    plt.plot(plotdata.loc[:,'Date'], plotdata.loc[:,'70d'], 'r', label='70d')
    legend = plt.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)
    plt.grid(True)
    rax = plt.axes([0.9, 0.91, 0.1, 0.1], frameon=False)
    check = CheckButtons(rax, ('Køb', 'Følg'), (False, False))
    def func(label):
        if label == 'Køb':
            with open('Køb.csv','a') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=" ")
                writer.writerow(ferm)
        elif label == 'Følg':
            with open('Følg.csv','a') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=" ")
                writer.writerow(ferm)
    check.on_clicked(func)
    plt.show()
```

One .csv in the DOWJones_stock directory has following data:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2015-12-31,52.799999,53.290001000000004,52.66,52.82,50.067657000000004,8292900
2016-01-04,52.009997999999996,52.610001000000004,51.610001000000004,52.48,49.745384,17174600
2016-01-05,52.790001000000004,53.470001,52.669998,53.150002,50.380466,11075500
2016-01-06,52.509997999999996,52.950001,52.209998999999996,52.419998,49.688507,12465900
2016-01-07,51.52,52.32,51.439999,51.959998999999996,49.252476,12720000
```

I have made some tests and it seems the line:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

is the main problem.
But why only on my 64-bit system.
The startplot date is plotted as 2017-01-01 00:00:00 but it is the same in both systems.

I do not like to update pandas on my 32-bit system if the problem is pandas version 0.21.0

Hope one of you more hard core guy's can help.

Regards Henning

Comment: After upgrading my 64bit system to Pandas 0.21.1 it is working again.